# Spring preAuthorize log result of the SpEL query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, pre-authentication

I have a method that can be executed when either of the authentication methods return true.

```
@PreAuthorize("canExec('ROLE_A') || canExec('ROLE_B')")
public String getSomething() {
    return "Something";
}
```

How can I log whether the authentication failed or succeeded, meaning the result of the whole SpEL query is true or false?

The following is not a possible solution, since it can be called multiple times in the same SpEL, and the multiple logged results would not reflect the actual result of the authorization.

```
public boolean canExec(String role) {
    boolean result = ...acutal evaluation...;
    log.info("auth result for role {}: {}", role, result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean canExecOr(String roleA, String RoleB) {
    boolean canA = canExec(roleA);
    boolean canB = canExec(roleB);
    // log...
   return canA || canB;
}

@PreAuthorize("canExecComposite('ROLE_A','ROLE_B')")
```

??

Comment: Updated so the roles can be logged.